# Problems with getting info from text files c++

Tags: c++

I'm rather new to C++ and I've been having trouble getting input from a text file.

Relevant code:

```
vector<string> nutrientName;
vector<float> nutrientAmount;
vector<string> nutrientUnits;
vector<float> nutrientCalories;

ifstream nutrientFile;
nutrientFile.open(nutrientFileName);
float newAmount = 0;
string newUnit;
float newCalories = 0;

while (!nutrientFile.eof())
{
    int place = 0;
    char nameArray [50];


   while(c != ';')
    {
        if (c != '\n')
            nameArray[place] = c;

        c = nutrientFile.get();
        place++;
    }

    string newName(nameArray, place);
    nutrientName.push_back(newName);

    nutrientFile >> newAmount;
    nutrientAmount.push_back(newAmount);

    nutrientFile >> newUnit;
    nutrientUnits.push_back(newUnit);

    nutrientFile >> newCalories;
    nutrientCalories.push_back(newCalories);

}

nutrientFile.close();
```

The input is a list of ingredients and some nutritional facts about them set up like this:

Ingredient1(1+ words); amountOfUnitsInServingSize(float) unitType(1 word) caloriesPerServing(float)
Ingredient2(1+ words); amountOfUnitsInServingSize(float) unitType(1 word) caloriesPerServing(float)

.

.

.

My problem is that when I try to bring stuff in from the file it gets stuck in either one of the while loops (if the inner one is commented out). When I throw debug code in, it indicates that it's not actually getting any input from the file.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To simply to to define nameArray as string and use << operator to extract nameArray. After that you can separate this string in tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 or 3 probleme.

**Look comment:**

```
while (nutrientFile.good() == true)   // use good() its more safe with your implementation
{
      int  place = 0;
      char nameArray [50];
      char c;                         // not defined    

      c = nutrientFile.get();         // was not init
      while (c != ';')
      {
             if (c != '\n')
                  nameArray[place] = c;
             c = nutrientFile.get();
             place++;
      }
      string newName(nameArray, place);
      nutrientName.push_back(newName);
      nutrientFile >> newAmount;
      nutrientAmount.push_back(newAmount);
      nutrientFile >> newUnit;
      nutrientUnits.push_back(newUnit);
      nutrientFile >> newCalories;
      nutrientCalories.push_back(newCalories);
}
```

Good Luck ;)

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem (well, this one). A few others popped up, but I managed to work through those. This one was just not going to fix itself easily for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the eof on the inner while loop also.